# Why doesn't Internet Explorer support web standards?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, web-standards

Ok, this may be a noobie question. And as the ol' saying says: "Google is your friend"... well, it didn't want to be my friend in this case.

It's a long known issue that IE is always the problematic browser that doesn't support web standards and makes you degrade your clean and tidy code with dirty hacks. But why?

What has to be developed by the browser developers that makes it so difficult for IE to follow standards while the rest of browsers support them easily? What needs to happen for a browser to recognize CSS properties? Is it the engine? Is it difficult to code? Why is it easier to code proprietary extensions instead of coding the actual CSS property to begin with?

I'm trying to understand why IE wouldn't want to follow web standards like every other browser.

With love,
A Nobbie.

Comment: This really should be in the past tense since IE has had great support for web standards for a good few years now (and even so, IE has really been supporting web standards to some degree since antiquity - no browser is perfect).

Comment: Cross-browser testing is something every developer should do simply because browsers are different by nature - that is by design. Since you're new, I'd advise you not to listen to those who always single out IE for its own sake. Like I said, no browser is perfect, but that doesn't mean IE "doesn't support web standards" as people so often like to claim.

Comment: IE9+'s DOM is mostly spec compliant, and IE10+ has decent CSS3 support. Honestly, a lot of today's spec compliant features that you can't live without nowadays were initially implemented by the old MS proprietary model (e.g. `mouseenter/leave` events, `clientWidth/Height` and `scrollTop/Left` DOM properties). And you do not necessarily have to support old browsers -- put a "Your browser is ancient, your security is at risk" warning or something in these lines with a link to http://browsehappy.com/ and be done with it. Help move the web forward instead of holding it back to old IE capabilities.

Comment: Also, look up the Graceful degradation and Progressive enhancement methodologies if you haven't yet.

Comment: First can you enumerate what standards you are looking for. From the looks of it you just want to be a hater. I invite you to check out http://status.modern.ie to see what IE does and does not support. I think you will find anything that has reached recommended standard is supported as well as many that are in various other states of the W3C approval process. As far as is a feature or standard supported the decision process varies starting with is the specification a security problem, are developers going to use it now, etc.

Comment: The only problem with IE is its relationship to the operating system. It is so tied in to the OS it can only be upgraded to certain versions on certain OS's. Also, in general, Microsoft make it more difficult than other browsers to upgrade. Upgrading from 8 to 9 to 10 to 11 is a massive deal. Not so, with major version changes on Chrome and Firefox. Safari on Apple suffers a bit like this too. If users are not on the current OS, they may get the outdated Safari 5 or 6. If everyone was on the latest browser regardless of OS (as with Chrome and Firefox), this wouldn't even be a topic.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is my thought:

1. MS was not motivated to become better because they were mostly monopolists. They are not monopolists here these days, so you can see they became much more motivated.
2. IE core is widely used in Windows, so it's hard for them to change their own standards.

Comment: That is neither correct or a real answer.

Comment: @XiruxNefer This is just must guess based on the life experience. I don't have any proof that can be verified easily.